# Why is int* arr = {}; legal?

Tags: c++11, initializer-list

```
int* arr1 = {}; //ok: arr1 == NULL
int* arr2 = {1,2,3};//error: scalar object requires one element in initializer
```

I expected the initialization of `arr1` to cause the same error, but it doesn't. Why is that?

**Edited:**

 Thank @krzaq for the answer. I did get confused with what you talked about.

 So the following statements are all legal:

```
int* arr1 = {};
int arr2[] = {1,2,3};
int* arr3 = {arr2};
```

Comment: `int* arr3 = {arr2}` just initializes the pointer `arr3` to the adress of the first element of `arr2`. It's not making it an array.

Comment: Yes; what I did only makes print `arr2` and `arr3` the same address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confused yourself with incorrect naming. `arr1` and `arr2` are pointers, not arrays. You can zero-initialize a pointer, and you did this with the exact syntax you used for `arr1`. You cannot initialize a pointer with a `std::initializer_list<int>`.

If this is still confusing to you, try reasoning about some abstract type:

```
using some_type = int*;

some_type foo = {}; // ok, value-initialized
some_type bar = {1,2,3}; // not ok, doesn't make sense to initialize 
                         // bar with a list of ints
some_type baz = "a string"; // also not ok, doesn't make sense
```